# Java - executing external exe file

Tags: java, exe

I have a executable program made on C++ (cf.exe) that takes parameters from a few text files (.txt), performs some calculations, and creates a file with the results (results.txt). This program needs no interaction. Once executed, when the calculations are done, it's automatically closed.

Then, I have other program made on Java, which contains a button that executes the cf.exe. When the button is pressed the following method is called:

```
    public void executeExternalProgram(){       
        String filePath = "C++" + File.separator + "cf.exe";
        try {           
            System.out.println("Executing C++ exe...");
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(filePath);;           
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
```

I don't get any error, but the cf.exe is not being executed when I press the button. When I execute manually the cf.exe, the results file is correctly created. Furthermore, I've tried to copy other programs, such as notepad.exe, to the same folder and execute it through Java without any problem. Can anyone see why it's not working?

Comment: Hm, I would print full file path and stuff; and for example make sure that the string really really points to an existing file. You could also println exitValue() from your process object.

Comment: Your path seems to be `C++\cf.exe` which would be relative to your application's current working directory. Please do what Jägermeister suggested and check/post your absolute path.

Comment: Yes, it's a relative path. I've tried with other programs and it's not a problem of the path

Comment: Well, you can be pretty sure that java process/runtime methods have been used a gazillion times by millions of people before. So "if it doesn't work"; most likely: because the input you give to it is somehow invalid. And beyond improved tracing and maybe switching to absolute path ... there isn't too much that could be done on this level.

Comment: if with other programs there are no problems, maybe it will be better if u provide the code of that C++ program u're trying to launch

Comment: @David Can you please put your program's file structure tree

Comment: The C++ program works perfectly. I push the button of the Java program and no results.txt is created. Then I open the cf.exe manually and the results.txt is created.

Comment: I've tried using the absolute path and the behavior is the same.

Comment: @Jägermeister, I've printed the exitValue of the process object as you suggested and I get the following error: java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: process has not exited
 at java.lang.ProcessImpl.exitValue(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0):

I found that changing the command given to the process makes it work correctly. The change is the following:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start "+ filePath);
```

Then, the updated code for the method called when the button is pushed:

```
public void executeExternalProgram(){       
    String filePath = "C++" + File.separator + "cf.exe";
    try {           
        System.out.println("Executing C++ exe...");
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start "+ filePath);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```